# Some pages extend their content horizontally, out of screen, when zoom in

Tags: google-chrome, browser, scrolling, zoom

(For Desktop)

Sometimes, when I'm reading, I raise the zoom level to ease the reading. In some cases this works well (for instance, superuser site), however, other sites (example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) don't respect the end of the screen and part of text is hidden (you need to scroll horizontally to see it).

Since this only happens in some sites, is obviously not Chrome's fault, but it would be nice if the browser could handle that.

(Android)

Same issue, although the zoom works a bit differently, and I'm not at all sure that would be possible for Chrome to "fix it".

.

(Out of curiosity, any other browser solves this issue? I think Opera sorted this out maybe 10 years ago, but nowadays being just a clone...)

Comment: I think such behavior dictated by CSS layout of a site - if you meant wrapping possibility on zooming

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [default font size](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96810?hl=en) in Chrome might help, but if what appears to be text is in actuality an image, there is no way to make it wrap -- it will be beyond the screen limits.

You might also use a third-party add-on such as [A+ FontSize Changer Lite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/a%20-fontsize-changer-lite/ckihgechpahhpompcinglebkgcdgpkil?hl=en), but I've not tried that myself.

Some browsers, such as Firefox, shown below, can force your customized fonts to be applied to *all* text, as shown below, but I don't know if that is true for Chrome.

[image: Firefox Font Customization]